# Php register tweeks using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

So ive got my connection to my database and ive got a nice little register script working using PDO. In my code it will die if; a username is not input into a field, the username is taken, the passwords do not match etc. I would not like it to die i would like it to echo out the "Please enter a username" so the user can correct the information and continue with the for.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(empty($_POST['Username']))
    {
        die("Please enter a username.");
    }

    if(empty($_POST['Password']))
    {
        die("Please enter a password.");
    }

    if(!filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        die("Invalid E-Mail Address");
    }

    $query = "
        SELECT
            1
        FROM users
        WHERE
            Username = :Username
    ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':Username' => $_POST['Username']
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row)
    {
        die("This username is already in use");
    }

    $query = "
        SELECT
            1
        FROM users
        WHERE
            Email = :Email
    ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':Email' => $_POST['Email']
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row)
    {
        die("This email address is already registered");
    }

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO users (
            Username,
            Password,
            salt,
            Email
        ) VALUES (
            :Username,
            :Password,
            :salt,
            :Email
        )
    ";
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

    $Password = hash('sha256', $_POST['Password'] . $salt);

    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
    {
        $Password = hash('sha256', $Password . $salt);
    }

    $query_params = array(
        ':Username' => $_POST['Username'],
        ':Password' => $Password,
        ':salt' => $salt,
        ':Email' => $_POST['Email']
    );

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    header("Location: login.php");

    die("Redirecting to login.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: wrap it all in a function and use `return` instead of `die`

Comment: im actually pretty new to all this, how would i do that and would it still make it safe?

Comment: You will need ajax so the form doesn't need to be submitted for the response to be returned. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: I was scared of that being the answer i have no idea how to use ajax :(

Comment: @nathzOO this is where you'd start to *learn* it. ;)

Comment: @nathzOO that would depend on you, each persons learning abilities are different.

Comment: You might want to try the [jquery form validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)